# Design pattern suggestion for keyword driven test framework

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm in the process of writing a simple keyword driven test framework.  It takes an xml file which contains actions.  I load these actions from the xml file during runtime, and using reflection, I call the corresponding method in c#.  Something roughly like this:

```
<Action>Launch
    <Application>Notepad.exe</Application>
    <RunElevated>True</RunElevated>
    <Test>ApplicationLaunch</Test>
</Action>
```

Launch would actulally be the name of a method.

What design pattern would match this problem the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you will use several design patterns depending on where you need extensibility, eliminate duplication, etc.

After parsing the XML you can create tests using a `Builder`.  Each test case could follow a `Command` pattern so the details of running and verifying tests is abstracted.

Some tests could be test suites that run multiple tests using the `Composite` pattern.

I recommend you look at the source of existing unit test frameworks for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

The one solution that I came up quickly is to build

```
Interface Operation 
{
   public Run()
}
```

Each object must implement it. Than to create a hash of objects that implements one interface
and knows how to Run different tasks. Key will be operation, execute the action.

The other idea is to use the fabric pattern and to create an object based on an operation.